# in pine script a variable will be initialize after every every candle close but i want dynamic variable

Tags: variables, pine-script, pine-script-v5

So i am creating one simple indicator in that i want a variable value to be initialized once condition is met for example if RSI goes below 40 then value of variable will be true now if it comes above 40 then again false but yeah i want it to go below 40 then comes above 40 there you can say its my buy signal as the value of variable gets initialize at every candle so its hard for me keep track of it whether it went below 40 and then came above 40 or not.
so it would be better if i could have a variable like wasbelow40=true and wasbelow40 value should now change in next candle until i change it with specific conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `var` variable. It will keep its value between each execution unless you explicitly assign a value to it.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var rsi_cond = false

rsi_val = ta.rsi(close, 14)
plot(rsi_val)
hline(40)
hline(60)

if (rsi_val < 40)
    rsi_cond := true
else if (rsi_val > 60)
    rsi_cond := false

bgcolor(rsi_cond ? color.new(color.green, 85) : na)
```

In this example, `rsi_cond` will be `true` once the RSI goes below 40 and it will stay `true` until the RSI goes above 60.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But this will only work on current candle. So consider that we have RSI and RSI based MA so if RSI and RSI based MA both goes below 40 then rsi_cond should be true then when both comes above 40 it should be false but sometimes it might happen that RSI went below 40 first then afterword RSI based MA also while coming above 40 one might come above 40 earlier than above thats why i want rsi_cond value should not get initialized at every candle close if i initialize it once as true then it should stay true until i change it. In your code it is initialized every time.

Comment: No, it doesn't initialized on every candle. `var` is a one time initialization process. After the initialization, it will keep its value unless you explicitly assign a new value to it as I stated. [Here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#kw_var) is the reference manual for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insights but could you please review below code which i wrote for  my earlier comment. Below code is not working as i am expecting so if you could help a little then it would be helpful. Thanks!

var wasBelow40 = false
buyCondition = rsi_val > 40 and rsi_ma > 40
buyConditionChanged = buyCondition and wasBelow20

if (rsi_val < 40 and rsi_ma < 40)
    wasBelow40 := true
else
    wasBelow40 := false